# sql query to obtain most number of names by year

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have a sample dataframe below that is over 500k rows:

```
|year|name|text|id|
|2001|foog|ltgn|01|
|2001|goof|ltg4|02|
|2002|tggr|ltg5|03|
|2002|wwwe|ltg6|04|
|2004|frgr|ltg7|05|
|2004|ggtg|ltg8|06|
|2003|hhyy|lt9n|07|
|2003|jjuu|l2gn|08|
|2005|fotg|l3gn|09|
```

I want to use sql to select the most popular name for each of the year. ie: it returns me a dataframe that has only most popular name per year for all the years that it has in the 500k rows.

I can do this via 2 separate statements:

```
-- sql query that gives me the names
select count(1), name from table_name group by name, order by count(1) desc limit 1;

-- If i add in a year parameter -> i can get for that particular year
select count(1), name from table_name where year = '2001' group by name, order by count(1) desc limit 1;
```

However how do I merge the query into 1 sql such that it provides me with the data of just the most popular name for each year?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is more than one name with the same top count in a year?

Comment: hmm. that is a good question. is it possible to dynamically take those results that tie? if not, just returns the top most result (i get that this is a bit random in some sense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select yn.*
from (select yn.*,
              row_number() over (partition by year order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from (select year, name, count(*) as cnt
            from table_name
            group by year, name
           ) yn
     ) yn
where seqnum = 1;
```

The innermost subquery calculates the count for each name in each year.  The middle subquery enumerates the names for each year based on the count, with the highest count getting `1`.  And the outer subquery filters to get only the name (per year) that has the highest count.

In most databases, you can simplify this to:

```
select yn.*
from (select year, name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by count(*) desc as seqnum
      from table_name
      group by year, name
     ) yn
where seqnum = 1;
```

I have a vague recollection that SparcSQL doesn't allow this syntax.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. the 1st aggregation and window function seems to work with sparksql. but not the 2nd. Could you please explain a bit more into what is happening for the 1st set of sql u shared?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Gordon! just 1 more question. what does `yn.*` mean? can't exactly find that information on google

Comment: @jakewong . . . `yn` is a table alias defined in the `from` clause.  `yn.*` is all columns that the table alias refers to.  It is a convenience, because that part of the query is not particularly important.  You can select whatever columns you want.